# When using GDB in C++ with Eigen, how can I see more of a big matrix?

Tags: c++, gdb, eigen

I am able to see so much of a matrix, but then it just says "..." and stops.  Is there a way to get the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the rest?

Try `(gdb) help set print elements` and `set print elements unlimited`.